# Use reflection for casting to unknown type

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

In my action I do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Overview(IDynamicList entity, int skip, int take)
{
    List<IEntityModel> model = getModel(entity.GetTypeName(), skip, take); 

    string viewName = entity.GetView();

    return PartialView(viewName, model);
}

private List<IEntityModel> getModel(string typeName, int skip, int take)
{
    string getComponentsMethodName = nameof(IContentQueryProvider.GetComponents).Split('.').Last();

    Type typeOfEntity = FindViewModelByTitle<IContentModelAttribute>(typeName);

    var data =
        typeof(IContentQueryProvider)
        .GetMethod(getComponentsMethodName, new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) })
        .MakeGenericMethod(new[] { typeOfEntity })
        .Invoke(_contentQueryProvider, new object[] { skip, take });

    return (data as IEnumerable<object>).OfType<IEntityModel>().ToList();
}
```

I want to cast the return object to `List<typeOfEntity>` instead, however the only thing I know is that `typeOfEntity` implements an interface that inherits `IEntityModel`. That's the reason I know that I can return `List<IEntityModel>` but then I can't get help from the intellisense later on in my views and I need to cast the model directly in my view instead. So how do I do the casting directly here in my controller so I can return something that makes sense directly upon arrival to the view?

Comment: Compiler knows as many as you in that case - you have no information about a type.

Comment: You can't cast if you don't know the static type, which you don't here. The earliest place you can cast is the point at which you 'know' what the concrete type should be.